# Javascript get value by radio button name

Tags: javascript

first of all i am a beginner in javascript, a really big beginer

Can someone give me a hint on this?

I have a `form`, on the form i have a `radio` button.

And i would like to that if the radio is set yes , it would show the value of it on another page.

And i would like to get the value by the input name

is it possible?

I'm not asking to write my code, but just an example for a start.

i was tried with this just for a test

```
<input type="hidden" name="the_name" value="yes">

if(the_name.element == 'yes') {
    alert('cool');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`the_name.value`, not `the_name.element`

Comment: thank you, and can you tell why im getting this error? the name is not defined?

Comment: Because it's not inside a form. Ideally you'll want `the_form.elements["the_name"].value`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementsByName()` for accessing the elements value via the input name. But as a standard and since it helps load off the DOM we use `getElementById()` instead of the name. Also you can start from here -> http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: The method you seek is *getElementsByName*, note the plural. There is no "getElementByNames" method.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the form using:

```
document.forms[formName or formId].elements[element-name];
```

However, name is not necessarily unique in the document. If there is only one element with the name, then only one is returned. If more than one have the same name, then you will get a collection (a bit like an array) and you will have to iterate over them to find the one you want.

You can also use [*document.getElementsByName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259), which always returns a collection. So you can do:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('the_name');
// get the one with value 'yes'
for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (elements[i].value == 'yes') {
    return elements[i];
  }
}
```

You will also need to be careful of case sensitivity, you might want to use *toLowerCase()* on the value first, or use a case insensitive regular expression:

e.g.

```
var re = /yes/i;
...
  if (re.test(elements[i].value)) {
    // value is Yes or YES or yeS or ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="the_name" id="the_name" value="yes"> <!-- id added -->

if(formName.the_name.value == 'yes') 
{
   alert('cool');
}
```

OR better (since you are not accessing the elements by global names)

```
var element = document.getElementById("the_name");
if(element.value === 'yes')
{
   alert("yes, it is");
}
```

Comment: really sorry but i feel like a complete noob, i keep getting element is null :S

Comment: @Side, `var element = document.getElementById("the_name");` gets the element with the id `the_name`. Did you add the `id` to the hidden element you have?